# Windows form setup error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, installation

i have folowing problem i create Windows Form using Entity framework setup and when i install and start application receive error message:

> No connection string named 'PhonebookEntities' could be found in the application config file

I use MS SQL Server 2012 database and this App.config connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="PhonebookEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/PhoneModel.csdl|res://*/PhoneModel.ssdl|res://*/PhoneModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NT2\SQLEXPRESS1;initial catalog=Phonebook;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="Phonebook1.Properties.Settings.PhonebookConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=NT2\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Phonebook;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: try to add this :
<remove name="PhonebookEntities" />
directly under <connectionStrings>

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx